# How to create this curved effect using flutter with clippath

Tags: flutter, dart

#### HOW TO CREATE THIS?

Its like a ListTile or something with this curve effect in start of it, as of now it won't animate just the next option will be selected `onTap` but I'm unable to create this effect. I tried it with `radius` but that's not resulting out to be exact match of this. The code is below.

[image]

#### MY TRY SO FAR

[image]

Code

```dart
   Container(
        color: AppTheme.c.primary,
        width: 200,
        height: 60,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 60,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                  right: Radius.elliptical(
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: funny thing, this is what I added today morning: https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312 - see "static #3" sample that is very similar

Comment: Man thank you!!
Let me get into this